# why the code of worksheet change not work?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote some codes for the data validation column to automatically generate cells and it was seemed to be worked in the first time, but after i closed file and open again, it didn't work.

Thank you help

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  Application.EnableEvents = False


Dim catCode As String

If Target.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Column = 2 Then

    catCode = Target.Value
    Select Case catCode
    
    Case "AUTOMATIC LEVEL", "DIGITAL LEVEL"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "19/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1

    Case "BAROMETER", "THERMOMETER"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "24/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "BRACKET BUBBLE"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "23/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 0.5
    
    Case "CARPENTER LEVEL", "REFLECTOR POLE"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "23/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 0.5
    
        
    Case "CLINOMETER", "TRIBRACH"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "23/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "DIPMETER"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "18/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    
    Case "DIGITAL MEASURING POLE"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "18/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "FIBRE GLASS / LENEN TAPE"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "18/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "STEEL POCKET MEASURING TAPE"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "18/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "STEEL TAPE", "STEEL RULER", "STILON TAPE"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "18/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    
    Case "DISTOMETER"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "27/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 2
    
    Case "GPS"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "21/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "HAND HELD LASER METER", "TOTAL STATION", "TOTAL STATION WITH REFLECTORLESS"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "20/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "LEVELLING STAFF - TELESCOPIC", "LEVELLING STAFF - NON BARCODE", "LEVELLING STAFF"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "22/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "MEASURING WHEEL"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "3/00"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "PLANIMETER"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "26/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "PLOTTER"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "28/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "SPRING BALANCE"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "24/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 2
    
    Case "EDM", "THEODOLITE"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "N/A"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    
    End Select
Else
Exit Sub

End If
ErrHandler:
   Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

Comment: You have an `Exit Sub` that doesn't need to be there... and if it gets executed, the `Application.EnableEvents = True` doesn't... so events aren't re-enabled.

Comment: but after I deleted the Exit Sub, it still no work!

Comment: In the Immediate Window, put `Application.EnableEvents = True` and hit Enter.

Comment: how to modify the code to work? thanks

Comment: And more when i view the code again, it always takes the long time to display the code, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the `Application.EnableEvents = False` inside the `If Target.Column = 2` block will prevent your code from exiting without resetting the  `Application.EnableEvents` flag.  Managing the `Application.EnableEvents` flag can become a problem as your code changes in the future (especially when using `Exit Sub` statements).  Another approach that avoids this problem is to handle the `Application.EnableEvents` flag management separately from your behavior logic...something like.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

On Error Resume Next     
    LoadCells Target

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub LoadCells(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim catCode As String

If Target.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Column = 2 Then

    catCode = Target.Value
    Select Case catCode
    
    Case "AUTOMATIC LEVEL", "DIGITAL LEVEL"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "19/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1

    Case "BAROMETER", "THERMOMETER"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "24/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "BRACKET BUBBLE"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "23/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 0.5
    
    Case "CARPENTER LEVEL", "REFLECTOR POLE"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "23/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 0.5
    
        
    Case "CLINOMETER", "TRIBRACH"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "23/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "DIPMETER"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "18/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    
    Case "DIGITAL MEASURING POLE"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "18/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "FIBRE GLASS / LENEN TAPE"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "18/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "STEEL POCKET MEASURING TAPE"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "18/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "STEEL TAPE", "STEEL RULER", "STILON TAPE"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "18/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    
    Case "DISTOMETER"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "27/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 2
    
    Case "GPS"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "21/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "HAND HELD LASER METER", "TOTAL STATION", "TOTAL STATION WITH REFLECTORLESS"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "20/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "LEVELLING STAFF - TELESCOPIC", "LEVELLING STAFF - NON BARCODE", "LEVELLING STAFF"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "22/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "MEASURING WHEEL"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "3/00"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "PLANIMETER"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "26/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "PLOTTER"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "28/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    Case "SPRING BALANCE"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "24/99"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 2
    
    Case "EDM", "THEODOLITE"
    Target.Offset(0, 7) = "N/A"
    Target.Offset(0, 8) = 1
    
    
    End Select
Else
    Exit Sub

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: BZngr, Thank you very much for your reply but why the code is still not working in my worksheet after i change the code as yours. Any further help?

Comment: It may be that your `Application.Events` flag is set to `False`.  If you are unsure how to use the Immediate Window to set it to `True` (as was suggested earlier) you can also write and run a macro containing a single statement: `Application.EnableEvents = True`.  Restarting Excel would be the next thing to do if you are not sure now to accomplish either of the above.

Comment: BZngr, is there anything to help my code problem as i have executed the Applction.enableEvents = true, but the worksheet still not taken action from the code and also why the code is nothing to display when open it. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: Not sure what else to provide.  I can run the code above and it seems to work fine.  I paste "AUTOMATIC LEVEL" in column 'B' and "19/99" shows up in column 'I' and "1" in column "J" for the same row.  I can only suggest that you make sure you are entering data in the worksheet associated with the module containing your code.

Comment: your are helpful, but one thing I forgot to tell that my column "B" is a data validation column which can select from the box, is it affected to the code?

Comment: `If Target.Column = 2 Then` ...so, yes.